# Oracle form 11g / 12c with Next and Previous button

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

Please help me understand the process on how we can achieve this.

I want to restrict the number of records being displayed in the canvas . If there are 1000 records in the datablock, then in the canvas I will restrict it to 100 records. For viewing the remaining 900 records we will have to provide the user with a next / previous button . When they press the next button then the next 100 records should be displayed and previous button the exact reverse.

Is this doable in Oracle Forms (like it is in Oracle Apex)?

If this is doable could anyone please provide a sample link so that I can do research on it. Not finding any good leads. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Forms doesn't work in *pages* (so that you could move from one page of records to another; something like Apex does). All records fetched into the tabular block are there, that's why you have a scrollbar.

Displaying 100 records is a little bit too much; you can't see it on the screen anyway. Consider lower number, e.g. 15 records at a time.

Then, you could create those `NEXT` and `PREVIOUS` buttons. Create `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` triggers on each of them. You'd use `:system.cursor_record` or `:system.trigger_record` as they show which record you're in now, and then move 15 records *up* or *down*. Something like this:

```
-- NEXT button:
go_record(:system.cursor_record + 15);
```

---

```
--PREVIOUS button:
go_record(:system.cursor_record - 15);
```

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot, are there any examples like the one you have explained ? So that it would be easier for me to implement them ?

Comment: You're welcome. Examples? I don't know; see Forms Online Help System, it has plenty of examples. It is available in Forms Builder's "Help" menu.

Comment: You could also use the SCROLL_DOWN and SCROLL_UP built-ins in the button triggers rather than go_record.

Comment: Nice, @Andy! Thank you!